# Content Security Policy error when trying to inject HTML, CSS, JS into webpage using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to show a notification popup on particular site by injecting it using Chrome extension. But the problem is that when I try to close the popup it shows content security policy error.

**Background script:**

```js
var usr_data = {
  name: "google.com",
  re_url: "www.google.com"
};

chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: 'var usr_data = ' + JSON.stringify(usr_data)
  }, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'notification.js'
    }, function() {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      }
    });
});
```

**Notification script:**

```js
(function() {

  //alert('Example:' + usr_data.point);

  var popup_script = document.createElement('script');
  popup_script.innerHTML = 'function hide() { var el = document.getElementById("promobox"); el.style.display = "none";} function activate() { document.getElementById("sb").value="Activated"; document.getElementById("sb").style.backgroundColor = "red";}';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(popup_script);

  var side_popup = '<div class="closepop" id="promobox" style="z-index: 10000;right: 25px;position: fixed;top: 20px;width: 345px;box-shadow: 0 0px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)"><form action="'+ usr_data.re_url +'" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="authToken" value="725625f1-a2d6-4c3b-a909-89d852fcb514"> '+
   '<div class="promo-text">'+
    '<div class="promo-close" style="width: 60px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;text-align: center;float: left;font-size: 10px;line-height: 11px;text-align: left;">'+
    '<a class="promoClose promoslider_close" title="Close" style=" display: inline;width: 20px;height: 20px;font-size: 12px;color: #fff;text-align: center;position: absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;line-height: 18px;cursor: pointer;" onClick="hide()" id="theButton">x</a></div>'+
   '</div><div class="promo-text">'+
    '<div style="background-color: #333;float: left;width: 100%;border-radius: 3px;">'+
     '<div style="float:left;width: 50%">'+
      '<div style="padding: 30px 20px;text-align: left;">'+
       '<div style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: #fff;">'+ usr_data.name +'</div>'+
      '</div>'+
     '</div>'+
     '<div style="float: right;width:50%;">'+
      '<div style="text-align: center;">'+
       '<input id="sb" type="submit" value="Get Vantage Points" onClick="activate()" style="font-size:13.5px; width: 150px; border: 0px; background-color: #2874f0;margin:27px 2px 7px;text-align:center;padding: 10px 0;border-radius: 3px;color: #fff;text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);cursor: pointer">'+
       '<div style="color: #ccc; font-size: 9px;text-align: right;margin-right: 20px;">Powered by Google</div>'+
      '</div>'+      
     '</div>'+
    '</div>'+    
   '</div>'+
     '</form></div>';

    document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',side_popup);

})();
```

Comment: This is the error message :

[Report Only] Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.example.com https://example.d1.sc.omtrdc.net https://dpm.demdex.net https://example.com https://example.com 'nonce-13899742927739567156' https://example.net". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: It means you can't use `onClick=` in HTML. Instead use addEventListener in js.

Comment: i have tried that but not working.

Comment: document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",function() {alert("Hii");}, true);

Comment: popup_script.innerHTML = 'document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click",function() {alert("Hii");}, true);  function activate() { document.getElementById("sb").value="Activated"; document.getElementById("sb").style.backgroundColor = "red";}';

Comment: is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Yes !! and any other solution?

Comment: I didn't got it. Can you please tell me a little bit briefly !!!

Comment: Yeah. Checked that . Still not working.

Comment: "Not working" isn't telling much. Also, you should use `popup_script.text =`, not `popup_script.innerHTML`.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you use `script` element. There's no need for that if you use addEventListener.

Comment: Thanks bro. its working now. I don't have that much of javascript knowledge. Thanks again.